# I can be printed, but I can't fit in your printer - what am I?

Tags: riddle

I know many ways to tell you where to go.

I can be printed, but I can't fit in your printer.

I'm sure you have days in which you say you feel like me.

I've been shot into that which I have held.

I'm here for support for one and all.

More than one of me sounds very similar to a place I've never known or shown.

---

SPOILER AND EXPLANATION OF ANSWER... Don't look unless you mean it...

Answer to Clue 1

> A type of map

Answer to Clue 2

> Atlas is a size of paper: [one source](http://www.papersizes.org/old-english-uncut.htm) that would not fit into modern, personal printers

Answer to Clue 3

> Atlas [One definition](http://a%20person%20who%20supports%20a%20heavy%20burden;%20a%20mainstay.) Describes a person who supports a heavy burden; a mainstay.

Answer to Clue 4

> The [Atlas Rocket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atlas_(rocket_family)) Has been shot into the sky / [Atlas](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/atlas) Classical Mythology. a Titan, son of Iapetus and brother of Prometheus and Epimetheus, condemned to support the sky on his shoulders: identified by the ancients with the Atlas Mountains.

Answer to Clue 5

> The [Atlas bone](http://www.getbodysmart.com/ap/skeletalsystem/skeleton/axial/vertebrae/atlas/tutorial.html) supports your head (you and all other humans)

Answer to Clue 6

> The [plural](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/atlas) for atlas is atlantes (look at definition for column structure atlas) which sounds similar to [Atlantis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atlantis), a place of fiction and thus no atlas would show.

I truly hope you all enjoyed this!

Comment: I was thinking about an (open) book or a map, but it's probably wrong.

Comment: You could always submit an answer with some reasoning and find out...

Comment: I read about the title `I can be printed, but I can't fit in your printer - what am I?` and I thought this was about 3D printing :)

Comment: yeah.... the general guidance I've received on titles for the 'who/what am i' riddles is to pick a clue and slap it in... I was hoping it would be a title that would grab attention

Comment: I thought it was fingerprint

Comment: @AminahNuraini that's an interesting one... I'd love to see the explain on the clues for that

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think you are

> not a map, but an atlas

I know many ways to tell you where to go.

> an atlas is full of maps to help you find directions

I can be printed, but I can't fit in your printer.

> as a bound book, you can print out the pages, but the book won't fit in a printer

I'm sure you have days in which you say you feel like me.

> This is where we start shifting to Atlas, the Greek Titan.  Some days, you feel like you have the weight of the whole world on your shoulders.

I've been shot into that which I have held.

> Except that Atlas didn't hold the world, he held the Heavens.  And Atlas rockets were the ones that launched the Mercury capsules in the space program.

I'm here for support for one and all.

> If Atlas held up the world, then he supported everyone.

More than one of me sounds very similar to a place I've never known or shown.

> Atlases sounds similar to Atlantis, which isn't on any map, so wouldn't be in any atlas.

Comment: Tell you why (and good job btw) in just a moment

Comment: See the updated post to show just how close (and of course right) you were... Kudos and Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  I thought my answer to 5 was weak; now I know why! (I didn't think my answer for #2 was as far off as it turned out to be.)

Comment: Still you got the answer, and the explanations you had made sense

Comment: Surely we have moved past the time when one of these wouldn't fit in my printer. [And then we've moved past the next time, too.](https://www.ebay.com/itm/DK-3D-Eyewitness-World-Atlas-CD-ROM-2003-/264285174998)

Answer (score 4):

You are:

> Space

I know many ways to tell you where to go.

> You can't go anywhere there isn't space to go.

I can be printed, but I can't fit in your printer.

> You can literally 'print' a space character, but all of space cant fit in your printer.

I'm sure you have days in which you say you feel like me.

> We've all spaced out every now and then

I've been shot into that which I have held.

> We've shot rockets with space in them into space

I'm here for support for one and all.

> Some just need a little space

More than one of me sounds very similar to a place I've never known or shown.

> Spaces are similar to places, but not very specific

Comment: +1 for the answer, though this is not it... very creative thinking though

Answer (score 3):

I'm a bit clueless, but I was thinking about

> a (treasure?) map or an (open?) book.

It's probably wrong. Also I'm not a native English speaker.

I know many ways to tell you where to go.

> for a map it's obvious, a book can also give you advise.

I can be printed, but I can't fit in your printer.

> obvious for both.

I'm sure you have days in which you say you feel like me.

> People can be an "open book" or "lost without a map".

I've been shot into that which I have held.

> Books hold opinions, for which people are shot. Treasure maps hold information for which people are shot.

I'm here for support for one and all.

> Books and maps help you.

edit, forgot this one. More than one of me sounds very similar to a place I've never known or shown:

> this vaguely resembles maps pointing to places the maps themselves have never been, or books take you to places the books themselves have never been.

Comment: So, this wasn't the correct answer- still not a bad one.
I'm wondering how you would fit the final clue into this answer... "More than one of me sounds very similar to a place I've never known or shown"

Comment: Ok, I think I was pretty close :)

Comment: You really were... super close!!!!

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to guess:

> An arrow.

I know many ways to tell you where to go.

> There are many types of signs that depict arrows showing the way to travel, etc.

I can be printed, but I can't fit in your printer.

> One can print an arrow on a piece of paper, but an arrow (as in the projectile) cannot fit inside a printer.

I'm sure you have days in which you say you feel like me.

> This one is kind of a stretch, but I suppose there are times where it feels like everyone is using you for direction.

I've been shot into that which I have held.

> The projectile is shot in a direction, which is the meaning the symbol holds.

I'm here for support for one and all.

> Not entirely sure on this one; maybe that signs themselves don't discriminate? Anyone can tell where an arrow is pointing.

More than one of me sounds very similar to a place I've never known or shown.

> This is the one that I don't get. It's either something to do with "arrows" or "quiver", but I can't think of a location that sounds similar to either of those, that would also be impossible to be indicated by an arrow. (Edit: Maybe an aquifer?)

Comment: Not the right answer, but +1 because I really liked some of the connections you made to the clues with your answer

Answer (score 2):

You are:

> a star.

I know many ways to tell you where to go:

> Directions by the stars

I can be printed, but I can't fit in your printer:

> A picture of a star can be printed, but a star is too big to fit in your printer.

I'm sure you have days in which you say you feel like me:

> I feel like a star!

I've been shot into that which I have held:

> I've been shot into the stars like a shooting star!

I'm here for support for one and all:

> Stars give guidance and direction.

More than one of me sounds very similar to a place I've never known or shown:

> The "stars" sometimes refers to a place (in space), but stars are too far away to be known or mapped.

Comment: +1 I like it. I find answers 4 and 6 to be a bit of a stretch... and ultimately this was not the correct answer. None the less I hope you enjoyed and as I said, I like your answer!